# Not supporting actionbar backward compatibility

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I want to use action bar in my project which have min sdk version 8. There for i use actionbarsharelock library to provide backward compatibility. But when i added library to project it gives error is R file missing. what goes wrong. Is there any other method to add library than normally we added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make following changes-
**1.** Import a actionbarsherlock library. 
**2.** Add actionbarsherlock-i18n to project libraries.
**3.** Make theme as Theme.sharelock in Manifest file.
**4.** And do some Syntacticla changes as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use actionbarsherlock Library.

Comment: please tell me what to do...?